# ON DELETE SET DEFAULT não funciona no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, sqlite3

Estou tentando deixar o valor `default` `'SEM CURSO'` na tabela aluno quando o curso for excluído, porém da forma que estou fazendo o valor da chave estrangeira não está ficando default e sim `NULL`. Estou fazendo o script da forma incorreta ou o PostgreSQL não suporta `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`?

O estranho é que mesmo que o PostgreSQL não suporte, o script roda normalmente.

Segue:

```sql
CREATE TABLE curso (
    nome varchar(30) primary key default 'SEM CURSO'
);

CREATE TABLE aluno (
    nro_matric int primary key,
    nome varchar(50),
    curso_id varchar(30),
        foreign key (curso_id) references curso(nome) on delete set default on update cascade
);

insert into curso(nome) values ('Sistemas de Informação');
insert into curso(nome) values ('Ciencia da Computação');

insert into aluno(nro_matric, nome, curso_id) values (201701, 'Marcio Alves', 'Sistemas de Informação');
insert into aluno(nro_matric, nome, curso_id) values (201702, 'Caio Ribeiro', 'Sistemas de Informação');
insert into aluno(nro_matric, nome, curso_id) values (201703, 'Leticia Alves', 'Ciencia da Computação');
insert into aluno(nro_matric, nome, curso_id) values (201704, 'Fabio Antonio', 'Sistemas de Informação');

delete from curso where nome = 'Ciencia da Computação';

select * from aluno;
```

Comment: Do manual: `SET DEFAULT

    Set the referencing column(s) to their default values. (There must be a row in the referenced table matching the default values, if they are not null, or the operation will fail.)
`

Comment: Testei com not null mas não funcionou tb, gostaria de saber como seria o script correto disso

Comment: Você precisa criar um registro na tabela `curso` com o campo `nome` = 'SEM CURSO' ou permitir que o campo `curso_id` da tabela `aluno` fique com NULL quando não estiver associado a curso.